# Новый проект qt приложение qt widgets выдает много ошибок. Как мне это исправить?

Tags: c++, qt

Новый проект qt приложение qt widgets выдает много ошибок. Приложение запускается, но если изменить код, перестает запускаться. Если редактировать форму, приложение запускается.[image]

Comment: вот тут посмотрите https://forum.qt.io/topic/107181/lot-of-errors-but-it-builds-and-runs-successfully

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58737644/18282426

Здесь описано как отключить модель clang, из за которой появлялись ошибки.

выбираем сверху `справка` -> `О модулях...` и отключаем `ClangCodeModel`